# Using XmlSerializer to serialize derived classes

Tags: c#, xml, polymorphism, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm using `XmlSerializer` to serialize an object that contains a generic list

`List <ChildBase> Children {get;set}`

The problem is that each element derives from `ChildBase` which in fact is an abstract class.
When I try to deserialize, I get an invalidOperationException

Is there a way I can use `XmlSerializer`  with derived objects?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are three ways of doing this; either you can use `[XmlInclude]` against the type, or you can use `XmlElement`/`XmlArrayItem` against the property. They are all shown below; uncomment the pair you prefer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
public class MyWrapper {
    //2: [XmlElement("A", Type = typeof(ChildA))]
    //2: [XmlElement("B", Type = typeof(ChildB))]
    //3: [XmlArrayItem("A", Type = typeof(ChildA))]
    //3: [XmlArrayItem("B", Type = typeof(ChildB))]
    public List<ChildClass> Data { get; set; }
}
//1: [XmlInclude(typeof(ChildA))]
//1: [XmlInclude(typeof(ChildB))]
public abstract class ChildClass {
    public string ChildProp { get; set; }
}
public class ChildA : ChildClass {
    public string AProp { get; set; }
}
public class ChildB : ChildClass {
    public string BProp { get; set; }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyWrapper));
        var obj = new MyWrapper {
            Data = new List<ChildClass> {
                new ChildA { ChildProp = "abc", AProp = "def"},
                new ChildB { ChildProp = "ghi", BProp = "jkl"}}
        };
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: And now try to apply this: [XmlRoot(ElementName = "myWrapper", Namespace = "http://URL/")]public class MyWrapper

Comment: Note that method 1 does not seem to work for deserializing a collection.  Method 2 or method 3 is needed for the deserializer to figure out how to map the nodes in the xml back to items in the collection.

Answer (score 5):

You may use [XmlIncludeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) for this. Or see [this](http://ozba.wordpress.com/2009/09/22/xml-serialization-derived-types-problem-can-be-resolved/) post on another way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the types dynamically from derived class if defined in another namespace:
[XmlAttributeOverride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides?view=net-6.0)