# How to use XmlSerializer to serialize derived instances?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, derived-class

I realize this looks to be an exact duplicate of [Using XmlSerializer to serialize derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643139/using-xmlserializer-to-serialize-derived-classes), but I cannot figure out how to get this working following the guidance from that same question:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace xmlSerializerLab
{
    public class Utf8StringWriter : System.IO.StringWriter
    {
        public override Encoding Encoding => Encoding.UTF8;
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Query", Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/wfs")]
    public class Query
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Filter", Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/ogc")]
        public Filter Filter { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(PropertyIsOpFilter))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(PropertyIsEqualToFilter))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(OpFilterBase))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(LiteralFilter))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Query))]
    [Serializable]
    public class Filter
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public Filter And { get; set; }
    }

    public class PropertyIsOpFilter : Filter, IXmlSerializable
    {

        public Filter LeftOp { get; set; }

        public Filter RightOp { get; set; }

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) { }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            Program.ToXml(LeftOp, writer);
            Program.ToXml(RightOp, writer);
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("IsEqualTo")]
    public class PropertyIsEqualToFilter : PropertyIsOpFilter { }

    public class OpFilterBase : Filter, IXmlSerializable
    {
        public string Op { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) { }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Op))
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement(Op);
                writer.WriteValue(Value);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteValue(Value);
            }
        }
    }

    public class LiteralFilter : OpFilterBase { }


    class Program
    {
        public static void ToXml(Object o, XmlWriter writer)
        {
            var inputSerializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType(), new Type[] {
                typeof(Filter),
                typeof(PropertyIsOpFilter),
                typeof(PropertyIsEqualToFilter),
                typeof(OpFilterBase),
                typeof(LiteralFilter),
                typeof(Query)
            });
            inputSerializer.Serialize(writer, o);
        }

        public static string ToXml(Object o)
        {
            var inputSerializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
            using (var writer = new Utf8StringWriter())
            {
                using (var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(writer))
                {
                    ToXml(o, xmlWriter);
                }
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Filter o = new PropertyIsEqualToFilter()
            {
                LeftOp = new LiteralFilter()
                {
                    Value = 1
                },
                RightOp = new LiteralFilter()
                {
                    Value = 1
                }
            };

            var query = new Query()
            {
                Filter = o
            };

            Console.WriteLine(ToXml(query));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It results in this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The type
>   xmlSerializerLab.PropertyIsEqualToFilter may not be used in this
>   context. To use xmlSerializerLab.PropertyIsEqualToFilter as a
>   parameter, return type, or member of a class or struct, the parameter,
>   return type, or member must be declared as type
>   xmlSerializerLab.PropertyIsEqualToFilter (it cannot be object).
>   Objects of type xmlSerializerLab.PropertyIsEqualToFilter may not be
>   used in un-typed collections, such as ArrayLists.

As far as I can tell, I need the IXmlSerializable on the PropertyIsOpFilter and OpFilterBase because I'm trying to target a specific XML format described by [this schema](https://github.com/ca0v/ogc-lab/blob/master/ogc-models/data/wfs/wfs-110/spec/wfs.xsd).  But I'm finding that I also have to make the Query class IXmlSerializable.

Here is a sample XML document that I'd like to be able to produce from the model:

```
<GetFeature xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  service="WFS"
  version="1.1.0"
  maxFeatures="0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
  <ResultType>Results</ResultType>
  <OutputFormat>text/gml; subtype=gml/3.1.1</OutputFormat>
  <Query
    d2p1:srsName="EPSG:4326" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <d2p1:Filter>
      <d2p1:IsEqualTo>
        <d2p1:PropertyName>Prop1</d2p1:PropertyName>
        <d2p1:Literal>1</d2p1:Literal>
      </d2p1:IsEqualTo>
    </d2p1:Filter>
  </Query>
</GetFeature>
```

By making the Query class IXmlSerializable and writing a good bit of WriteXml and ReadXml logic I can get it to work, but I'd expect it to work without having to do all that since the XmlRoot and XmlAttribute and XmlElement tags should give enough information to the serializer for it to know which class to instantiate based on the tag name (match ElementName) and certainly how to serialize based on the attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem** you are seeing can be reproduced with the following minimal example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass, IXmlSerializable
{
    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) { }

    #endregion
}
```

Using the serialization code:

```
BaseClass baseClass = new DerivedClass();

using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseClass), new Type[] { typeof(DerivedClass) });
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, baseClass);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(textWriter.ToString());
}
```

The following exception is thrown (sample [fiddle #1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HjQ2Cn)):

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. 
---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type DerivedClass may not be used in this context. To use DerivedClass as a parameter, return type, or member of a class or struct, the parameter, return type, or member must be declared as type DerivedClass (it cannot be object). Objects of type DerivedClass may not be used in un-typed collections, such as ArrayLists.
```

This is among the most unhelpful exception messages I have seen from `XmlSerializer`.  To understand the exception, you need to understand how `XmlSerializer` handles polymorphism via the [`[XmlInclude]` mechanism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute(v=vs.100).aspx).  If I remove `IXmlSerializable` from `DerivedClass`, the following XML is generated ([fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TGRsvY)):

```
<BaseClass xsi:type="DerivedClass" />
```

Notice the `xsi:type` type attribute?  That is a [w3c standard attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) that `XmlSerializer` uses to explicitly assert the type of a polymorphic element; it is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx).  When `XmlSerializer` is deserializing a polymorphic type to which `[XmlInclude]` attributes have been applied (either statically or through the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5aakyae.aspx) you are using), it will look for the `xsi:type` attribute to determine the actual type to construct and deserialize.

It is this, apparently, which conflicts with [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx).  A type which implements this interface should *completely* control its XML reading and writing.  However, by parsing and interpreting the `xsi:type` attribute, `XmlSerializer` has already begun *automatic* deserialization, and so throws an exception due to the inconsistent deserialization strategies of the base and derived types.

What's more, adding `IXmlSerializable` to the base type doesn't really fix the problem either  If you do so, the `xsi:type` attribute is never written, and later, when `ReadXml()` is called, an object of the base type will get unconditionally constructed, as shown in [fiddle #3](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nHC3kw).

(It's conceivable that Microsoft could have implemented a special case where `XmlSerializer` begins automatic deserialization, then "backs off" and hands the task over to `ReadXml()` when an `IXmlSerializable` polymorphic type is encountered and constructed.  But, they did not.)

**The solution** would seem to be to serialize your `Filter` types automatically using the  `[XmlInclude]` mechanism.  In fact I don't see any reason you need to use `IXmlSerializable`, and was able to serialize your model successfully by removing `IXmlSerializable` completely and making some minor changes to namespaces:

```
public static class XmlNamespaces
{
    public const string OpengisWfs = "http://www.opengis.net/wfs";
}

[XmlRoot(Namespace = XmlNamespaces.OpengisWfs)]
public class Query
{
    public Filter Filter { get; set; }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(PropertyIsOpFilter))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(OpFilterBase))]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = XmlNamespaces.OpengisWfs)]
public class Filter
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Filter And { get; set; }
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(PropertyIsEqualToFilter))]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = XmlNamespaces.OpengisWfs)]
public class PropertyIsOpFilter : Filter
{
    public Filter LeftOp { get; set; }

    public Filter RightOp { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("IsEqualTo", Namespace = XmlNamespaces.OpengisWfs)]
public class PropertyIsEqualToFilter : PropertyIsOpFilter { }

[XmlInclude(typeof(LiteralFilter))]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = XmlNamespaces.OpengisWfs)]
public class OpFilterBase : Filter
{
    public string Op { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(Namespace = XmlNamespaces.OpengisWfs)]
public class LiteralFilter : OpFilterBase { }
```

Notes:

- For the `[XmlInclude]` mechanism to work, all the included types apparently must be in the same XML namespace as the base type.  To ensure this I added `[XmlRoot(Namespace = XmlNamespaces.OpengisWfs)]` to all the `Filter` subtypes.
- The `[XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedType))]` attributes can be added either to their immediate parent type or to the lowest common base type.  In the code above I added the attributes to the immediate parent types so that members of an intermediate type could be serialized successfully, e.g.:

  ```
  public class SomeClass
  {
      PropertyIsOpFilter  IsOpFilter { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Consider marking intermediate types that cannot be instantiated as `abstract`, e.g. `public abstract class Filter`.  Consider marking types that are "most derived" as `sealed`, e.g. `public sealed class LiteralFilter`
- If you use the `new XmlSerializer(Type, Type [])` constructor, you must statically cache the serializer to avoid a severe memory leak, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23897411/3744182).  It's not necessary in my solution but you are using it in your question.

Sample [fiddle #4](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mg1pSn) showing that the following XML is generated successfully:

```
<Query xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
  <Filter xsi:type="PropertyIsEqualToFilter">
    <LeftOp xsi:type="LiteralFilter">
      <Value xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Value>
    </LeftOp>
    <RightOp xsi:type="LiteralFilter">
      <Value xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Value>
    </RightOp>
  </Filter>
</Query>
```

Comment: Great answer!  Two of my colleagues offered the same solution but did not articulate it this well!  But I am not at liberty to change the XML format.  I'm trying to produce XML compatible with OGC WFS.  One of the more complex examples can be found here: https://github.com/ca0v/ogc-lab/blob/master/ogc-models/data/wfs/wfs-110/spec/getfeature-example-09.xml.  I will update the question to include this important constraint.  Based on your analysis, it seems like XmlInclude is off the table.

Comment: @CoreyAlix - perhaps you need to ask a second question then.

Comment: you answered my explicit question (yes, it can be done) and my implicit question (no, I cannot get the XML I'm looking for w/out writing IXmlSerializable classes).

Comment: @CoreyAlix - actually, you *probably* can, by using [`XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-control-serialization-of-derived-classes) instead of `XmlInclude`.  But we'd need to see the desired XML rather than the desired classes, which is why I'm suggesting you ask another question.