# How can you remove the type attribute from a KnownType in a DataContract class?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, datacontractserializer, datacontract

Is it possible to use the KnownType's class name as the tag, rather then the parent classes? e.g.

This is an excerpt from a larger DataContract xml file,

```
[DataContract (Namespace = "projectNamespace")]
[KnownType(typeof(Warning)), KnownType(typeof(Error))]
public abstract class Message
{
    protected Message(LogLevel logLevel, int percentUsed, string message)
    {
        this.LogLevel = logLevel;
        this.LogMessage = message;
        this.Percent = percentUsed;
    }

    internal readonly LogLevel LogLevel;
    [DataMember] internal readonly int Percent;    
    [DataMember] internal readonly string LogMessage;
}

[DataContract (Name="Warning", Namespace = "projectNamespace")]
internal sealed class Warning : Message
{
    public Warning(int percentUsed, string message) : base(LogLevel.Warn, percentUsed, message)
    {
    }
}

[DataContract(Name = "Error", Namespace = "projectNamespace")]
internal sealed class Error : Message
{
    public Error(int percentUsed, string message) : base(LogLevel.Error, percentUsed, message)
    {
    }
}

public enum LogLevel
{
    Warn, Error
}
```

What I saw:

```
<messages>
  <Message i:type="Warning">
    <PercentUsed>75</PercentUsed>
    <LogMessage>75% used</LogMessage>
  </Message>
  <Message i:type="Error">
    <PercentUsed>100</PercentUsed>
    <LogMessage>0% remaining</LogMessage>
  </Message>
</messages>
```

Expected:

```
<messages>
  <Warning>
    <PercentUsed>75</PercentUsed>
    <LogMessage>75% used</LogMessage>
  </Warning>
  <Error>
    <PercentUsed>100</PercentUsed>
    <LogMessage>0% remaining</LogMessage>
  </Error>
</messages>
```

Note how the Message has an annoying `i:type="Error"` rather then just being a `<Error>`

Comment: I believe `DataContractSerializer` only supports the `KnownType` mechanism, which is equivalent to `[XmlInclude]` with `XmlSerializer`.  There's no data contract equivalent to the [`[XmlElement(Type = typeof(ChildA))]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643139/using-xmlserializer-to-serialize-derived-classes) technique of `XmlSerializer` for handling polymorphism.

Comment: @dbc as far as I can tell, you are correct. I ended up just ignoring it.

Comment: Note to others following this code, it currently has a bug where the base constructors are never called, due to DCS, you need to create a deserialization callback