# Property of DataContract class as a QName element in generated soap message

Tags: c#, soap, datacontractserializer, datacontract, soapcore

I'm trying to serialize below class using the SoapCore and **DataContractSerializer** the way the property that holds object (TestProperty) is omitted in the soap message and the element name defines its type name (SomeType in this example)

```cs
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(SomeType))]
[KnownType(typeof(SomeType1))]
[KnownType(typeof(SomeType2))]
public class TestClass {
   public string Prop1 {get;set;}   
   public string Prop2 {get;set;}
[DataMember]
   public object TestProperty { get;set; }
}
```

The desired output would look like this:

```xml
<TestClass xmlns="...">
   <Prop1>test</Prop1>
   <Prop2>test</Prop2>
   <SomeType></SomeType>
</TestClass>
```

..instead of what the DataContractSerializer produces now:

```xml
<TestClass xmlns="...">
   <Prop1>test</Prop1>
   <Prop2>test</Prop2>
   <TestProperty i:type="SomeType">...</TestProperty>
</TestClass>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?
I need this in order to keep compatibility with a system written in c++, which expects the element and its type to be declared as a element having type as name instead of using i:type attribute.

Comment: Not without implementing `IXmlSerializable`.  `XmlSerializer` supports polymorphism by element name as well as by `xsi:type`, see [Using XmlSerializer to serialize derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643424/3744182).  `DataContractSerializer` only supports the latter.

Comment: See e.g. [How can you remove the type attribute from a KnownType in a DataContract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48533107/3744182) or [Can I 'override' Name for DataMember in Derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55881454/3744182) both of which are unanswered.  See also [Serialize a list of objects inheriting from class A to xml, so the names of the elements in the xml are B,C,D](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50471935/3744182) whose answer proposes switching to `XmlSerializer` as a workaround.