# XMLSerialize List of base type causing error of unknown types

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, generic-collections

I'm trying to serialize a List which can hold objects of the child classes. I need it to lack any parent tag, so XMLElement on the List has helped with that. My problem is with the reflection of the List not knowing what the child tags are.

**I have found that my issue comes in when I add the [XmlRoot] tag to the class that represents my root element.**

`[XmlRoot("EFilingBatchXML", Namespace = "www.fincen.gov/base", IsNullable = false)]
public class XmlRoot`

**Before that the List works and I can use either [XmlInclude] for the child classes, or include a Type[] when making the XmlSerializer. There is the small issue of it including the attribute:**

> xsi:type="Child"
>
> xsi:type="Adult"

**So it looks like the Root tag is causing my problem, but I will need to know how to exclude those attributes as well.**

Ex)

```
[XMLElement("Person")]
public List<Person> PersonList { get; set; }
.
.
PersonList = new List<Person>() {
    new Child(), new Adult()
};
```

I need it to format as such

```
<root>
...
    <Person>
        <Person elements>
        <Child elements>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Person elements>
        <Adult elements>
    </Person>
...
</root>
```

I always get the error

> Child was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm running out of ideas, and have no idea why the Type[] solution doesn't work for this.

Comment: To get a node per element; use `[XmlElement]` instead of `[XmlArray]`

Comment: The Net method for serializing expects a single note at the root.  the is why having an array of Person is giving an error.  Having a single Person element at the root does not give an error.

Comment: @MarcGravell yeah I've gotten that far with using [XmlElement] but I can't add child classes to the List without getting the error.

Thanks

Comment: @jdweng The Person element isn't at the root, I just didn't include the whole structure. My conflict is with the fact that my List<base class> which holds derived child elements, fails at runtime due it saying it doesn't know about the child classes. Nothing I've tried rectifies that. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you may be trying to deserialize a to a polymorphic type hierarchy where `Person` has subclasses `Child` and `Adult`.  If that's correct, this would seem to be a duplicate of [Using XmlSerializer to serialize derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643424/3744182).  As shown there, you would apply `[XmlElement("Child", Type = typeof(Child))]` to your list.  But if that doesn't work for you we would need to see a [mcve] showing your `Person`, `Child` and `Adult` types as well as the complete required XML.

Comment: @dbc That thread gets me close, but just like the XmlArray example, the serialization won't let me define each one with the same name of 'Person'. I get another InvalidOperationException saying that an XML element of Person is already present in the current scope. Is there any way, or attribute I can use to tell it to ignore that? That thread mentions doing the XmlInclude attribute on the abstract class of Person, but that hasn't helped at all in my case.

Comment: @Omen_20 - then to help you any further we need you to [edit] your question and include a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.  I'm not sure I understand your problem just from this comment thread.

Comment: @dbc I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Root root = new Root() {
                PersonList = new List<Person>() {
                    new Person() {
                        person = "Person1",
                        child = "Child1"
                    },
                    new Person() {
                        person = "Person2",
                        adult = "Adult2"
                    }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME,settings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, root);
        }
    }
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement("Person")]
        public List<Person> PersonList { get; set; }

    }
    public class Person
    {
        [XmlElement("Person")]
        public string person { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Child")]
        public string child { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Adult")]
        public string adult { get; set; }
    }
}
```