# XML serialization of a list containing both base and derived type objects

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize an object containing a List of base and derived types. The sample code snippet given below. When the list is having only base objects the serialization works correctly. But when I add an object of type '`CompositeElement`', `Serialize()` call shows exception.

> "InvalidOperationException: The type SerializeTest.CompositeElement
>   was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to
>   specify types that are not known statically."

Is there any method to serialize a list of mixed type like this?

```
private void Save(String path)
{
    ConfXML confXML = new ConfXML();
    confXML.ElementList = new List<Element>();

    // Add base element
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        confXML.ElementList.Add(new Element(Type.Element, i.ToString()));

    // Add composite element
    CompositeElement compElement = new CompositeElement(Type.CompositeElement, "Composite", "Sensor1");
    confXML.ElementList.Add(compElement);

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfXML));
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces nameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        nameSpace.Add("", "");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, confXML, nameSpace);
    }
}

public enum Type
{
    Element,
    CompositeElement,
}

public class ConfXML
{
    private List<Element> elementList;

    [XmlElement("Elements")]
    public List<Element> ElementList
    {
        get { return elementList; }
        set { elementList = value; }
    }
}

public class Element
{
    private Type type;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public Type Type
    {
        get { return type; }
        set { type = value; }
    }


    private String name;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public Element(Type typ, String nam)
    {
        this.Type = typ;
        this.Name = nam;
    }

    public Element()
    { }
}

public class CompositeElement : Element
{
    private String compData;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public String CompData
    {
        get { return compData; }
        set { compData = value; }
    }

    public CompositeElement(Type typ, String nam, String data) : base(typ, nam)
    {
        this.CompData = data;
    }

    public CompositeElement()
    {}
}
```

Comment: This error message says exactly what you need to do to solve it :) Add `[XmlInclude(typeof(CompositeElement))]` and voila

Comment: When I use `XMLInclude`, the XML file looks like this `<Element Name="Composite" Type="CompositeElement" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" CompData="Sensor1" d2p1:type="CompositeElement">`. Is there any way to get rid of the `xmlns:d2p1` part?

Comment: No. If you remove it, then how would deserializer know what is the actual type of your `Element`?

Comment: Or, you can nest your list inside some container root object and use `[XmlElement("CompositeElement", Type = typeof(CompositeElement ))]` as shown in [Using XmlSerializer to serialize derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643424/3744182).  In fact I think this is a duplicate.  Agree?