# How do I use XmlSerializer / Deserialize dynamically without using if or switch case?

Tags: c#, xml

This is my 3 sample xml files:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ABC>
  <Header>
    <Date>2020-03-20T09:08:29Z</Date>
    <Code>A101</Code>    
  </Header>
  <Document>
    <AAA>Test Data 123</AAA>
    <BBB>Test Date 456</BBB>
  </Document>
</ABC>

<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ABC>
  <Header>
    <Date>2020-03-20T09:08:29Z</Date>
    <Code>A106</Code>    
  </Header>
  <Document>
    <MMM>Test Data 123</MMM>
    <ZZZ>Test Data 456</ZZZ>
    <CCC>Test Data 888</CCC>    
  </Document>
</ABC>

<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ABC>
  <Header>
    <Date>2020-03-20T09:08:29Z</Date>
    <Code>A100</Code>    
  </Header>
  <Document>
    <QQQ>Test Data 999</QQQ>
    <LLL>Test Data 000</LLL>
  </Document>
</ABC>
```

Notice that the `Header` schema is the same but the schema inside `Document` tag are different based on the `Code` tag

And here are my classes. Since the `Header` is the same, I move the `Header` to another class.

```
namespace Model.A100
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Document")]
    public class Document
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "QQQ")]
        public string QQQ { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LLL")]
        public string LLL { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ABC")]
    public class ABC
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header")]
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Document")]
        public Document Document { get; set; }
    }

}

namespace Model.A101
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Document")]
    public class Document
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AAA")]
        public string AAA { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BBB")]
        public string BBB { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ABC")]
    public class ABC
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header")]
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Document")]
        public Document Document { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Model.A106
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Document")]
    public class Document
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "MMM")]
        public string MMM { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ZZZ")]
        public string ZZZ { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CCC")]
        public string CCC { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ABC")]
    public class ABC
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header")]
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Document")]
        public Document Document { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Model
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Header")]
    public class Header
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

To deserialize to Xml to C# object,

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model.Header));

using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)))
{
    var obj = (Model.Header)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

   // do something
}
```

Now that I can extract out the `Header`, how do I do the same for the `Document` tag which is based on `Code` tag? Surely, I can't be writing `if statement` or `switch case`.

Comment: Write custom serializer.

Comment: `XmlSerializer` supports two mechanisms for deserializing polymorphic subtypes.  The type can be specified by an `xsi:type` attribute, or by using different element names. See [Using XmlSerializer to serialize derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1643139/3744182) for details.  Your case doesn't match either of these patterns, so manual deserialization looks necessary.

Comment: Why do you care when you are deseriailizing?  Make one class with all the properties and then handle the different cases after you parse the xml.